# :codeigniter login form validation always fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am following the tutorial in this page http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2016/06/codeigniter-login-and-registration-tutorial-source-code.html and me and other people had found the same error.

It appers to be something wrong in the login controller because it always shows the "Wrong Email-ID or Password!" message, even when the credentials are fine, but I can not find the mistake (although I had found and solved some others), please help me.

controller:

```
<?php
class login extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url','html'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}
public function index()
{
    // get form input
    $email = $this->input->post("email");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");
    //(This was added later for me, as it was needed)
    $this->load->helper('security');
    // form validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email-ID", "trim|required|xss_clean");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required|xss_clean");

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // validation fail
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else
    {
        // check for user credentials
        $uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($email, $password);
        if (count($uresult) > 0)
        {
            // set session
            $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->fname, 'uid' => $uresult[0]->id);
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            redirect("profile/index");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email-ID or Password!</div>');
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }
  }
}
```

related part in the view:

```
<?php $attributes = array("name" => "loginform");
        echo form_open("login/index", $attributes);?>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Email-ID</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email-ID" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
            <button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
```

If i did not explained myself clearly, or if you need to see more code, you can check it directly on the tutorial link.

Your help will be much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
This is the function in the model:

```
function get_user($email, $pwd)
{
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($pwd));
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    return $query->result();
}
```

I had already change "pwd" for "password" and removed the md5 as I dont need it,and now its working.

Comment: `if (count($uresult) > 0)` is equal to zero, you need to have a look at the `get_user` function and see whats happening there.  Also I presume you do have the user in the database yeah?

Comment: Database connection and data are OK, as I can add new users

Comment: Ok, but the count of result is still zero, hence why it is going into the else and giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

The form is validating OK as you are getting to this line:

```
$uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($email, $password);
        if (count($uresult) > 0)
```

Check your get_user function to make sure you are returning the result set, ie:

```
$this->db->where('user_email', $user_email);
$result = $this->db->get('users');

return $result->result();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in to the right direction, the variable name in the function was different. Now its working!

Comment: No worries - glad it was a simple fix!